# OS X + tmux + vim + solarize + colors

Tags: vim, tmux

I want to use tmux with console vim having solarized colors on OS X, but the colors are broken inside tmux. There are quite some questions/answers and blog posts about that topic, but solutions sometimes even contradict each other and non worked for me. As questions and blog posts are also dated, it's hard to figure out which versions have been used, ...

Can somebody specify a working solution for my requirements? I don't have any special requirements on my terminal emulator, so I'm open to use whatever works with tmux and vim.

Comment: might be a good idea to provide some of those links, or listing the techniques you've tried, so that answers don't end up referring to something you've already tried.

Comment: I have a problem that I won't describe and I've tried many solutions that I won't describe either. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Given a lack of provided details in the question, I will post what I did with my setup to have things work 'correctly' with iTerm2 + ssh + tmux + WeeChat/Vim

I have found that the soloarized 'presets' for iTerm2 do not play nice with 256 colors, besides the main 16 it uses.

- Examples: [No soloarized](http://demure.sdf.org/posts/Sol_without.png) vs [Default Solorized iTerm2 preset](http://demure.sdf.org/posts/Sol_with-norm.png)
- Notice the missing colors between the two.

To fix this (mostly) I use [Solarized High Contrast Dark](https://gist.github.com/heisters/1015503) instead.
This makes 256 colors work, although slightly 'off'.

After using the High Contrast version, I chose to disable the solarized.vim plugin, as it no longer looked right. (In addition, If I don't have access to solarized on a workstation, it might look off anyway; so more compatibility!)

All the above is with my $TERM and programs set properly, and not forced with an over-riding export.
iTerm2 reports xterm-256color, tmux is set to screen-256color

- See why [forcing $TERM is bad](http://blog.sanctum.geek.nz/term-strings/).